# 1146 "app_name.django_site missing"

Tags: mysql, django, django-sites, django-mysql

I am using Django 1.11 for making an app 'cnfs', and I am using MYSQL database with it. I am constantly facing this issue where I am getting an error like this when I type the following code:

```
$python manage.py migrate
```

> System check identified some issues:                                                                                                                                                      WARNINGS:                                                                                    ?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'                       HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode       Operations to perform:                                                                         Apply all migrations: admin, auth, cnfs, contenttypes, sites                               Running migrations:                                                                            No migrations to apply.                                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                             File "manage.py", line 22, in                                                          execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line                                                           utility.execute()                                                                          File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 355, in execute                                                                             self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)                                    File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv                                                                           self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)                                                         File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute                                                                                 output = self.handle(*args, **options)                                                     File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 227, in handle                                                                      self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias, apps=post_migrate_apps, plan=plan,     File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 53, in emit_post_migrate_signal                                                                  **kwargs                                                                                   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in send                                                                                     for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)                                               File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/management.py", line 20, in create_default_site                                                                  if not Site.objects.using(using).exists():                                                 File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 670, in exists                                                                                       return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)                                               File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 517, in has_results                                                                              return compiler.has_results()                                                              File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 845, in has_results                                                                           return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))                                                      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 886, in execute_sql                                                                           raise original_exception                                                                 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'cnfs.django_site' doesn't exist")

I have literally spent days on this, I did not face this issue when i was using the default django database engine, sqlite3.
I have tried doing this:
    $python manage.py migrate sites

My SITE_ID setting is set to 1.
I tried removing the 'django.contrib.sites' thing from the INSTALLED_APPS  setting, but that throws this error:

> Internal Server Error: /                                                                     Traceback (most recent call last):                                                             File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner                                                                                 response = get_response(request)                                                           File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 138, in **call**                                                                                   response = self.process_request(request)                                                   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subdomains/middleware.py", line 62, in process_request                                                                                super(SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware, self).process_request(request)                        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subdomains/middleware.py", line 38, in process_request                                                                                (self.get_domain_for_request(request), request.get_host()))                                File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subdomains/middleware.py", line 31, in get_domain_for_request                                                                         return get_domain()                                                                        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subdomains/utils.py", line 12, in current_site_domain                                                                                 from django.contrib.sites.models import Site                                               File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 84, in                                                                                  class Site(models.Model):                                                                  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 118, in **new**                                                                                       "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)                                                       RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please untag django-mysql from this question, that tag is supposed to mean for the library called 'django-mysql' which you aren't using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uncomment the `django.contrib.sites` from installed apps

then

```
python manage.py migrate sites
python manage.py migrate
```

if you have few table in the database, drop the tables and then run this